# Java Lock - Unlock

Tags: java, locking, reentrantlock

```
   java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;                             

   Public boolean ABCD(final AbcModel abcModel) {
    final Lock lock = (Lock)this.xyz.get((Object)abcModel);
    lock.lock();
    try {
        return super.ABCD(abcModel);
    }
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Does this method make threads and resources remain lock?

Comment: What's `this.xyz`? Why would you need to cast the `get()`-result to `Lock`?

Comment: After reading this many times I still can't understand what's your actual question. Seems like a XY problem.

Comment: Something looks wrong: that code doesn't compile...

Comment: Don’t focus on that part. Just think that I lock some object, then i return something in “try” part before i unlock it.

Comment: I had to change the names i’m sorry about that

Comment: @ovuncdeniz4 The locking pattern looks standard if that's what you are asking.

Comment: So is it okey if i return something before i unlocked the object? @assylias

Comment: `finally{}` part is being executed, no matter what happens earlier in `try` or even in `catch` if that's what you're asking. `lock` is being unlocked no matter what happens earlier.

Comment: That’s the answer what im expecting. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ovuncdeniz4 You can find the answer in [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) too.

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal Anyway, don't post answer in comment.

Comment: @user202729 I think it should be treated more like a hint than an answer. I avoided to dive into details as OP hasn't put too much effort to make prior research on his own.

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal Agree (about the "effort" part). But I think it's possible to put hint in answers. Let me check meta...

Comment: (sorry, I flagged the wrong question, I retracted the flag)

Comment: @PrzemysławMoskal [Apparently...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284347/to-give-or-not-to-give-a-hint-in-comments)

Comment: @user202729 Feel free to write an answer, if - in your opinion - it's worth that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this method make threads and resources remain lock?

No.  The lock will be unlocked (released) in the `finally` block.  This will happen *after* the `super.ABCD(abcModel)` call completes, and *before* the result of that call is returned.

This follows directly from the specified behavior of `finally`; e.g. see [JLS 14.20.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2) or [Exceptions > The finally block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) on the Java Oracle Tutorial which states:

> *"The runtime system always executes the statements within the finally block regardless of what happens within the try block."*

---

<sup>... though it mentions JVM exit as an exception to "always" a few sentences earlier.</sup>